# Aplicación MVC + Web APi con error en un ApiController que no se da en otro

Tags: api, mvc, web

Estoy armando una Aplicación MVC que incluye recursos de Web API para proveer acceso a dos tipos de tareas diferentes, en dos controllers diferentes. Se usa Ninject como resolucion de dependencias.
En ambos casos posee métodos POST que reciben un objeto de tipo complejo. Uno es un documento comercial y otro los datos de un cliente.
Las pruebas funcionan perfectamente cuando envío el Cliente al ClienteController, que posee un constructor con inyección de dependencias, recibe correctamente por FromBody el objeto con sus datos, y puedo hacer todo lo necesario.
Pero cuando envío el Documento al DocumentoController y su método, nunca recibe el objeto, aunque el método de envío sea exactamente el mismo desde el cliente. Me devuelve un Error 500, y cuando verifico con Tellerik Fiddler, el error devuelto por la aplicación indica que no existe un constructor sin parámetros (usa tambien inyección de dependencias), cuando el otro Controller tampoco lo tiene y funciona sin errores.
En resumen: Ambos controllers están construidos de la misma forma, y la única diferencia es que reciben objetos diferentes. Pero uno funciona y el otro no. Me tiene desconcertado.
Constructor del ClienteController

```
public ClienteController
    (
    ILogServices logsWs,
    IClienteService clienteService)
{
    _clienteService = clienteService;
    _logsWs = logsWs;
}
```

Constructor del DocumentoController:

```
public DocumentosController(
    ILogServices logsWs,
    IDocumentosContablesService procesaDocumentosService,
    IDocumentumService documentumService,
    IDocumentoContableService documentoService,
    IEntidadesService entidadesService
    )
{
    _logsWs = logsWs;
    _procesaDocumentosService = procesaDocumentosService;
    _documentumService = documentumService;
    _documentoService = documentoService;
    _entidadesService = entidadesService;
}
```

Ya he verificado que al llamar al ClienteController, se ejecuta sin problemas el constructor. Pero cuando llamo al método del DocumentoController, el constructor nunca se ejecuta.

Es como si no pudiera resolver la inyección de dependencias, y no tengo ni idea de por qué. Ambos controllers fueron creados de la misma forma, solo que se dedican a tareas diferentes.

¿Por dónde debería empezar a revisar?

Posdata:
El Cliente es una clase que contiene datos string, con uno de ellos como List de strings. Funciona sin problemas
El Documento es un objeto que contiene otros objetos (4 objetos), que a su vez son todos datos String o numéricos. En el caso del documento realicé pruebas para verificar si renviando sólo uno de los objetos, el mas simple, era recibido por un método específico, y tampoco llega. Es decir, no es el tipo de objeto el problema, es simplemente qu eno se inicializa el constructor.

Esto es lo que muestra el Fiddler al obtener el fallo:

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DocumentosController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
  "exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "stackTrace": "   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
  "innerException": {
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "El tipo 'PDC.Web.Api.Web.Controllers.DocumentosController' no tiene un constructor predeterminado",
    "exceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
    "stackTrace": "   en System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Tienes traza completa del error? ¿Podrías agregarla a la pregunta pulsando en [edit]?

Comment: No puedo capturar desde la aplicación cliente mas que el Error 500.
Desde el Fiddler solamente la respuesta de que no se encuentra constructor sin parámetros, que en caso exitoso no sucede.
Puedo verificar que la petición entra a la aplicación, porque pasa por el bloque de autenticación de usuario, pero en cuanto sale validado, pierdo completamente la trazabilidad.

Comment: Revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15908019/5587982) y su respuesta.

Comment: Estoy leyendo el link.
Lo que me sigue intrigando es por qué un controller funciona y el otro no. No parece razonable, y no encuentro el motivo.

Answer (score 0):

Pues finalmente, ,y luego de revisar mucha documentación, en diversos foros, y luego de hacer un análisis comparativo de los dos controllers (el que funcionaba y el que no), encontré el problema, gracias a la inspiración de una frase que decía "es posible que ocurran errores de DI en las clases cuya interface se intenta inyectar en una capa anterior".

En primer lugar, lo que noté es que si desactivaba la inyección de dos de las dependencias, la llamada desde el cliente web y desde Fiddler entraba perfectamente al método. Es decir que NO era que fallara la inyección en si, sino que fallaban DOS de las inyecciones de dependencia. Lo que implicaba que las clases que implementaban la interfaz tenían algún tipo de error.
Analizando las clases, una tenía un defecto de acceso a un web service, que voy a analizar después. Esa no me preocupa porque el WS aún no es operativo y es mersamente informativo.
La segunda clase tiene más de una docena de dependencias inyectadas, la mayoría son de lectura y solo cuatro son de escritura a la base. Esa si es compleja.
Revisé TODAS las clases y a primera vista no encontré errores, asi que le puse puntos de detencion en cada una y debuguee.
Al final, toda la ruptura se produjo en una única clase. Cuando la miro en detalle, me encuentro con que **no era pública**...

Diez días trabado buscando el error por todos lados, y al final era un miserable "public" faltante...

Moraleja: Cuando la Web API no parezca responder a las ID, antes de intentar magia, revisen las clases de nuevo. VARIAS VECES. Incluso las partes obvias.

Gracias de todos modos a todos.